# How can I read edges from a cluster of E

Tags: orientdb

I can run a query such as follow to read edges from cluster 1,2 of IP class:

select from cluster:[ip_1, ip_2]

but I can't run such a query for all edges:

select from cluster:[e_1, e_2]

It always returns null. Would you mind telling me how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your case and it works for me:

[image]

Probably it return null because the edges aren't in the clusters.

Try tu execute:

```
select from cluster:e_1

select from cluster:e_2
```

if both queries return null it means that there are not data into it.

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: I have three edge classes extended from E and I want to read edges from each cluster of the classes in parallel way using Apache flink. When reading edges from each clusters of the classes, it works fine and I can read edges of class A using: select from cluster:a_i which i is iterating number of clusters of class A(if i=0, select from cluster:a). But when I want to read all edges (all three classes of A,B,C), it doesn't work and returns null. I use this query: select from cluster:e_i which i is iterating number of clusters of class E. While select from E returns all edges.